# Order items not changed after moving objects inside list by remove and add

Tags: c#, list, element, move

it seems the old indexes are retained when moving items in an collection, how can I enasure that the items will be iterated in the new order with the new index after an move?

First I move items in an ordinary List:

```
elements.Remove(src);
int index = elements.IndexOf(target);
elements.Insert(index,src);
```

and then run an foreach loop

```
foreach(Element _element in elements){ /* enter code here*/ }
```

and it will retain the items with in order they were before relocation.

Comment: I've given you a down vote because it is very hard to understand your question. if you fix it, I'll give you an up vote instead.

Comment: have reformatted the code - you were referring to Elements / elements - these are presumably the same object, just a typo with the capitalization?

Comment: The sample code you posted doesn't help to demonstrate the problem. Generally speaking, a list does not magically remember the index of a previously removed item and use that index instead of the one passed to Insert

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your problem with this code and it writes to Console 0 1 2 3 5 6 4 7 8 9 as expected.

```
        List<string> elements = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            elements.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        string src = "4";
        string target = "7";

        elements.Remove(src);

        int index = elements.IndexOf(target);
        elements.Insert(index, src);

        foreach (string e in elements)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", e);
        }
```

So, with your current code I don't see where the problem could be.