# Sort a list to place an element at the top

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Vehicles>` which contains 4 items:

My `Vehicles` object has 2 properties: `VehId`, `VehName`

The 4 items in my list are:

1) `VehId : "LOR", VehName : "Lorry"`

2) `VehId : "CAR", VehName : "Car"`

3) `VehId : "BOA", VehName : "Boat"`

4) `VehId : "PLN", VehName : "Plane"`

What I'd like to do is put `Car` vehicle to the top of the list. How would I do this? By using `.OrderBy()` or `.Sort()`?

Comment: I assume you want the sort result persisted? Sort is in place on `List<T>` whereas `OrderBy` returns an ordered enumerable to iterate. It is always going to be car? If so, simply [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) at the relevant index beforehand and avoid sorting all together.

Comment: What criteria are you using to sort it? "Car" is not the first alphabetically [nor the last .

Comment: Yeah I know that Car is not first alphabetically, its just the most popular option that user's select so that is why I wish to put it at the top of my list.. so its the default option..

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Alternatively, sort alphabetically but have the underlying data default to Car anyway, then bind it to the UI control, which should then select car from the list regardless of where it is. The net result being the user doesn't actually have to do anything for that value most of the time.

Comment: Basically you just want to put car at 1st position, without checking for any constraints right .

Comment: [Similar question same goals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289464/order-items-not-changed-after-moving-objects-inside-list-by-remove-and-add)

List<Vehicles> varname..... fetch carVehiclesObject.... 
varname.Remove(carVehiclesObject);
varname.Insert(0, carVehiclesObject);

blind coding should be something near this

Comment: Unless you want to change the order of everything else then a sort isn't what you want `List.Insert` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) which would allow you to put an item in at the beginning. You'll probabyl need to remove it from the list first too.

Comment: Do you need to keep the order of the other elements ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is using `Enumerable.OrderBy:`

```
var ordered = vehicles
        .OrderByDescending(v => v.VehId == "CAR")
        .ThenBy(v => v.VehName);
```

here's a demo: http://ideone.com/QAgzd

Answer (score 2):

Implement `IComparable<Vehicle>` with the criteria you would like, then use Sort.

Comment: get Vehicle to implement IComparable<Vehicle>. The criteria used could be Car first, then alphabetical.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
vehicles.Sort((a,b) => -(a.VehId == "CAR").CompareTo(b.VehId == "CAR"));
```

if you want, you can apply the same logic for the `IComparable<Vehicle>` implementation, in this way:

```
class Vehicle : IComparable<Vehicle>
{
    public int CompareTo(Vehicle other)
    {
        int c = (this.VehId == "CAR").CompareTo(this.VehId == "CAR");
        return c;
    }
    // other class code...
}
```

and then you can simply call `vehicles.Sort()` to get the car at the beginning.